# How do I destroy an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I have a loop-all button and a stop button.  Both buttons work fine while I'm still on the page.  The problem is when I hit the loop-all button, it plays a series of audio files as it is supposed to, but when I leave the page (i.e. hit the phone's back button) and come back to the page, the audio doesn't stop!  I hit the stop button, but it does nothing.  The only way to stop it is to go into task manager and end the program.  It seems to me that the reference of mp2 gets lost once I leave the page...Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
                      public class OneVoc extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView lv;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private MediaPlayer mp2;
int[] myAudio = {R.raw.v_1100, R.raw.v_1101, R.raw.v_1102, R.raw.v_1103, R.raw.v_1104, R.raw.v_1105,
        R.raw.v_1113, R.raw.v_1106, R.raw.v_1107, R.raw.v_1108, R.raw.v_1109, R.raw.v_1110, R.raw.v_1112, 
        R.raw.v_1114, R.raw.v_1115, R.raw.v_1116};
int mCompleted = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one_voc);

    Button btnLoop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mp2 != null) {

                if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
                    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(null);
                    mp2.stop();

                }
                mp2.reset();
                mp2.release();
                mp2 = null;
            }


            }
    });

    btnLoop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), myAudio[0]);
            mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2)
                {
                    mCompleted++;
                    mp2.reset();
                    if (mCompleted < myAudio.length) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mCompleted]);
                            if (afd != null) 
                            {
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                afd.close();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } 
                    else if (mCompleted == myAudio.length) 
                    {
                        mCompleted =0;
                        try
                        {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mCompleted]);
                            if (afd != null) 
                            {
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                afd.close();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mCompleted=0;
                         mp2.release();
                         mp2 = null;
                    }

                }
            });


            mp2.start();  

        }

    });
```

Comment: try the method `finish()`

Comment: override Activity onPause() (don't forget to call super.onPause();)

Comment: In your onDestroy() method of activity, try to perform click on btnStop(btnStop.performClick();). But make sure that btnStop does not refer to null.

Answer (score 0):

try overriding onbackpressed method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         // code here to stop and finish()
         super.onBackPressed();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an It's an Audio buffer issue, memory is loaded in audio buffer and persist later on,finish() might not help u.
When u press back button on an android button it simply calls the finish() for current activity, while when u press home button it calls onPause(),
You need to override onBackPressed() method, and before line super.onbackPressed();
Put your code to stop playing. 
When u go to TakMgr it simply get's the PID refer to ur App process and kills the process.
Which is like System.exit(0); or android.os.process.kill(getMyPid());
Which simply ends ur app which u do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pause your mp in onPause() and restart it in onResume()?
Maybe you want also to store in savedInstance at which point you were!

Hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

when you back press the activity just stop the mediaplayer and free the resources and finish the activity.that's it..!

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         btnStop.performClick();
         super.onBackPressed();  
    }
```

Comment: I'm a newbie to java coding.  I'm learning as I go...Where exactly do you put the code above in my code??

Comment: just put that in you activity class

Comment: Where in the activity class?  I've put it everywhere and I get red squiggly lines???  Please show me exactly where.  I'm confused.

Comment: just put it above your onCreate() method

Comment: I've added the override code onBackPressed above, and I get a null exception error.  WTF?  Why is this so difficult?  Someone please help!!!